# Latex - \addsec and headsepline

Tags: latex

When I write `\addsec{Acronymes}`, LaTeX puts it in the Table of Contents and DOES the headsepline section. When I write `\addsec*{Acronymes}`, LaTeX doesnt put it in the Table of Contents and doesnt write it in the headsepline section. But I want that it doesnt appears in the Table of Contents and does appear in the headsepline.

So how do it?

Thats what I've done for this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, german, headsepline, footsepline, listtotoc, bibtotoc]     {scrartcl}
\bibliographystyle{annotate}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

%head and footsepline
\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\ihead{my title}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ifoot{my name}
\ofoot{\pagemark}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
citecolor=blue,
filecolor=blue,
linkcolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue
}


\begin{document}

\input{include/Abstract}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\addsec*{Acronymes}
%\addsec{Acronymes}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{HTTP}{Hypertext Transfer Protocol}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Comment: LaTeX related questions are best posted at [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can momentarily remove the functionality of `\addcontentsline` - the macro in charge of adding elements to the ToC - using

```
{% \begingroup
 \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Remove functionality of \addcontentsline
 \addsec{Acronymes}%
}% \endgroup
```

Grouping via `{` and `}` ensure that the command redefinitions are restored after the group ends.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks. Can you just explain why there is a "3" in the brackets?

Comment: The `\addcontentsline` macro is used in the form [`\addcontentsline{<file>}{<sec_unit>}{<entry>}`](http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/latex-help/ltx-193.html) which takes 3 arguments. I've just redefined it to still take 3 arguments, but do nothing with them. That is, it just gobbles them up. Also see [help with `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand`](http://www.public.asu.edu/~rjansen/latexdoc/ltx-18.html).